# Did the European clones know each other?

Tags: orphan-black

Katja Obinger locates Beth Childs and convinces her to look for clones in (Canada, I presume), based on the fact that a number of Eurpean clones had been murdered. How did Katja know about the murders? Where did her information come from? Most importantly, was she acquianted with any of the European clones before their untimely deaths?

It seems from the show that Beth was the first or only clone Katja had direct contact with, but in that case, how did she come by the case files of the other clones? In particular since they are all of different nationalities.

Comment: I got the impression that Katja had known of at least one other, but was not positive they were clones, hence the need to retrieve the briefcase. To the best of my recollection, they have not yet gone into specifics about clones in Europe.

Answer (score 6):

It is implied, but not certain, that Katja (Germany) had had some contact with the known European clones Janika (Austria), Aryanna (Italy), Danielle (France). The best clue is the length and complexity of the riddling "clone code phrase" that Katja tries on Sarah when she becomes suspicious that Sarah is not Beth:

**"[Just one. I'm a few, no family, too. Who am I?](http://orphanblack.wikia.com/wiki/Katja_Obinger)"**

Although there is no mention of the origin (which clones made it up) of this password/passphrase, it's not a simple word combination. Thus it could be inferred that it has been in use by Katja for a period of time in Europe, as it rolls off her tongue quite easily. It's possible that the original North American trio (Beth, Cosima, Alison) made it up, but still, it certainly sounds like Katja was very familiar with it.

Also, it is reasonable to further assume that Katja must have had contact with the other Europeans *because* she knew about the murders.

Comment: Regarding the phrase: it was confirmed in "[Orphan Black #1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_Black:_Sarah)" that [Beth created it as a sign and countersign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZTjo.png)